# At what value of $\alpha$ is the area of the cone least

Tags: calculus, geometry

A cone is circumscribed about a sphere of radius R.The vertex angle in the axial section of the cone is $2\alpha$Find the area of the axial section of the cone.At what value of $\alpha$ is the area of the cone least?
[image]

Comment: I believe it might not be true that the perpendicular from centre of sphere on side(radius you've drawn)  divides side of triangle/cone equally

Comment: Why do you describe the problem in three-dimensions when everything relevant is two-dimensional?

Comment: Sorry about that i thought it was not obvious that we were in 2d so i wanted to put stuff in 3d

Answer (score 1):

**For the first part:**

Let $h$ denote height or altitude of the triangle (axial section) , then:

$A=\frac{1}{2}\cdot 2r\cdot h=r\cdot h$

Now:

$h=R+\frac{R}{\sin\alpha}=R\left(1+\frac{1}{\sin\alpha}\right)$

On the other hand:

$r=\left(R+\frac{R}{\sin\alpha}\right)\cdot \tan\alpha=R\left(1+\frac{1}{\sin\alpha}\right)\tan\alpha$

So:

$A=R^2\left(1+\frac{1}{\sin\alpha}\right)^2 \cdot \frac{\sin\alpha}{\cos\alpha}$

$A=R^2\left(\frac{1+\sin\alpha}{\sin\alpha}\right)^2 \cdot \frac{\sin\alpha}{\cos\alpha}$

$A=R^2(1+\sin\alpha)^2\cdot \frac{1}{\sin\alpha\cos\alpha}$

$A=\frac{2R^2(1+\sin\alpha)^2}{2\sin\alpha\cos\alpha}$

$A=\frac{2R^2(1+\sin\alpha)^2}{\sin 2\alpha}$

**For the second part:**

To find at what value of $\alpha$ the area of the cone is the least you have to find the first derivative of $A$ with respect to $\alpha$ and equalize it to zero in order to find [stationary points](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StationaryPoint.html). Once you have a stationary points you need to perform [Second Derivative Test](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SecondDerivativeTest.html) in order to find a local minimum.

Answer (score 0):

I'll find the area of triangle without assuming that sides are bisected at point of contact with circle

Area=$\frac{a^2sin2\alpha}{2}=area\ of\ three\ triangles=2.\frac{1}{2}aR+\frac{1}{2}rR$

Here $r=asin\alpha$

Solving for r and a from these and then finding area, it comes out to be the same as required.

I'll solve it here(using r in above equation and simplifying, we get)-

$\Rightarrow asin2\alpha=2R(1+sin\alpha)\Rightarrow a=\frac{2R(1+sin\alpha)}{sin2\alpha}$

which gives $Area=\frac{2R^2(1+sin\alpha)^2}{sin2\alpha}$

Comment: Sorry i messed up the symbols many times I've edited it